# How to display nested array of Node, children objects as a table in HTML

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I currently have an EmployeeNode struct that represents a company Org Tree with the root EmployeeNode representing the CEO of the company. It looks like below:

```
type EmployeeNode struct {
    UserName string  
    Children   []*EmployeeNode
}

root := {
      UserName: "Bob Wang",
      Children: [
         {
            UserName: "Jim Halpert",
            Children: [
               {
                  UserName: "Brett Wang",
                  Children: []
               },
               {
                  UserName: "Ryan Wang",
                  Children: []
               }
            ]
         }
         {
            UserName: "Michael Wang",
            Children: [
               {
                  UserName: "Annie Wang",
                  Children: []
               },
               {
                  UserName: "Jay Wang",
                  Children: []
               },
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Given this sample root data, how can I dynamically generate an HTML table in Golang using HTML templates, that shows the Org Tree like below?:

[image: Org Chart]

Each EmployeeNode can have many children, or no children and I want to dynamically display this nested list structure as a table in HTML. I already know how to pass this EmployeeNode struct to a HTML template in Golang, but just not sure how to actually create the tables dynamically using this EmployeeNode struct. Thanks!

Comment: One way to do it is by using nested tables. Each table would have one row, and one col for each child. Each child would have another nested table in it. If you want to do this in a single table with multiple rows, first you need to compute the max number of cols in any row, and build each row with `colspan`s

Answer (score 0):

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Organization Chart</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/jquery.orgchart.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    var datasource = {{.}};

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : datasource,
      'nodeContent': 'title'
    });

  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

type EmployeeNode struct {
    UserName string          `json:"name"`
    Children []*EmployeeNode `json:"children"`
}

var root EmployeeNode = EmployeeNode{
    UserName: "Bob Wang",
    Children: []*EmployeeNode{
        &EmployeeNode{
            UserName: "Jim Halpert",
            Children: []*EmployeeNode{
                &EmployeeNode{
                    UserName: "Brett Wang",
                    Children: []*EmployeeNode{},
                },
                &EmployeeNode{
                    UserName: "Ryan Wang",
                    Children: []*EmployeeNode{},
                },
            },
        },
        &EmployeeNode{
            UserName: "Michael Wang",
            Children: []*EmployeeNode{
                &EmployeeNode{
                    UserName: "Annie Wang",
                    Children: []*EmployeeNode{},
                },
                &EmployeeNode{
                    UserName: "Jay Wang",
                    Children: []*EmployeeNode{},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", tree)
    // http://localhost:9090/
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}

func tree(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("template.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    data, err := json.Marshal(root)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tmpl.Execute(w, string(data))
}
```

**Working image of dynamic Tree**

[image]

Comment: I need to format it in an HTML table with very simple styling like in the image attached to this post, because this org chart is being dynamically created and sent through Gmail, which gets rid of a lot of CSS styling unless it's done through inline CSS. I've tried external libraries like these but none of the borders or connector lines show up when sent through Gmail.